# i have converted a animation python program to an .exe file but on opening the .exe file cmd popups and after 4-5 seconds it closes automatically

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have created the file by using the pyinstaller module in python
**[This is the Error I get on running the .exe file]**  CLick on the "1000" to see the error image file ==>  [1000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qd7NE.png)

**The Code of the Animation file is given below, i have converted this code to .exe file using pyinstaller module in python**

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

FPS = 60000000000000
fpsClock = pygame.time.Clock()

dis = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))
white = (255,255,255)
pygame.display.set_caption("Cat Animations !")

catImg = pygame.image.load('cat.png')
catx = 5
caty = 5
direction = 'right'

while True:
    dis.fill(white)

    if direction == 'right':
        catx +=5
        if catx == 270:
            direction = 'down'
    elif direction == 'down':
        caty +=5
        if caty ==270:
            direction = 'left'
    elif direction == 'left':
        catx -=5
        if catx ==5:
            direction = 'up'
    elif direction == 'up':
        caty -=5
        if caty ==5:
            direction = 'right'
    dis.blit(catImg, (catx,caty))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
    pygame.display.update()
    fpsClock.tick(FPS)
```

Comment: You need to copy the `cat.png` file to the exe location or specify the full location of `cat.png` in the program.

Comment: Prudhvi isn't there any other way to run the file without putting the image file externally.

Comment: you can check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use relative path. Add this function in your program and specify your path as `resource_path("cat.png")`. Change you statement to `catImg = pygame.image.load(resource_path('cat.png'))`:

```
def resource_path(relative_path):
    """ Get absolute path to resource, works for dev and for PyInstaller """
    try:
        # PyInstaller creates a temp folder and stores path in _MEIPASS
        base_path = sys._MEIPASS
    except Exception as e:
        base_path = os.path.abspath(".")

    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)
```